# how to use mysql_fetch_array without while loop

Tags: php

hey i want to use php mysql_fetch_array to fetch full table data at a time for that i use

```
while($user_details_result[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($user_details_qr));
```

but it returns a blank array at last like below

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
            [user_name] => w
            [user_login_id] => w
            [user_login_password] => w
            [user_contacts] => w
            [user_status] => 0
            [user_post_date] => ::1
            [user_post_ip] => 2014-03-07 16:17:59
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [user_name] => q
            [user_login_id] => q
            [user_login_password] => q
            [user_contacts] => q
            [user_status] => 1
            [user_post_date] => ::1
            [user_post_ip] => 2014-03-07 16:14:23
        )

    [2] => 
)
```

i dont understand why 3 rd row appears..please help

Comment: can you use another loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
while($temp=mysql_fetch_assoc($user_details_qr)) {
    user_details_result[] = $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` will return `FALSE` if there is no more row in the resultset. If you write `FALSE` into `$user_details_result[]`, that will become a blank array.

https://www.php.net/manual/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Try this

```
while($cur_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($user_details_qr)) {
  if($cur_row !== FALSE) { $user_details_result[] = $cur_row; }
}
```

But I think it should even work without the `if`, just like this (test it):

```
while($cur_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($user_details_qr)) {
  $user_details_result[] = $cur_row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using like this

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($user_details_qr))
{
     if (count($row) > 0)
          $user_details_result[] = $row;
}
```